# Custom editText on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, frontend, android-custom-view

I'm newbie with android layout, so i need some help.

I want create a custom editText, something like this:

[image: An email field with this blue "bar" in the left side]

I'm want to fix that with the best possible way.

Someone?

Thanks.

Comment: This already exists. Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and look for MaterialEditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the blue line on the left, you can just set the background on the EditText, such as,

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Then create another file in your drawable folder this is called custom_layer.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="-5dp"
        android:right="-5dp"
        android:top="-5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/color_of_the_background" />
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/color_of_the_border" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And a final selector file -  `custom_edittext.xm`.

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_layer">        
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

U can create a [Shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) drawable and set shape drawable as the EditText background