# Cursor is not visible in empty custom EditText on KitKat

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created a custom `EditText` class that extends `android.widget.EditText`. When running the app on KitKat and previous OS versions, if the custom `EditText` is empty, the cursor does not appear. It will appear once text is entered.

I have tried multiple solutions posted on this site including adding `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` and `android:textIsSelectable="true"` to the XML as well as adding those properties programmatically. None of these solutions has worked.

The custom `EditText` does have a background I am setting, but it needs to be there. Design constraints mean that I must set a non-default background.

So the question is, how do I make the cursor appear when the custom `EditText` is empty?

Here is the XML for the custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.CustomEditText
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text_background"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:padding="@dimen/custom_padding"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textColor="@color/custom_color"/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution I found is to set a `minWidth` on the custom `EditText`. A value of `40dp` worked for me. Now the cursor will appear in the view, even when empty.

Comment: And the reason the width must not be 0 is because that doesn't leave any room to display the cursor.  ...just discovered this.

Comment: Save my one hour, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just adding the solution that worked for me:
I set the `hint` property on `EditText`. Cannot be empty though, so I used a whitespace.

In my case `android:hint=" "`

Answer (score 0):

For starters, remove one item at a time from the XML.See if the cursor is being affected by anything else first (such as `android:gravity="start"` or `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"`).

Then post your `@drawable/custom_edit_text_background` so we can see the XML. Finally, post your class `CustomEditText`. You may have inadvertently caused an issue in there.

---

These may help:

- [Custom editText on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940725/custom-edittext-on-android?rq=1)
- [Custom EditText - Material Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811454/custom-edittext-material-design?rq=1)
- [Edittext cursor is invisible in android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093758/edittext-cursor-is-invisible-in-android-4-0)
- Attribute `textCursorDrawable` is available in API level 12 and higher
- `android:cursorVisible="true"`
- [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color?rq=1)

Comment: As stated in the question, I already tried the solutions you suggested. They did not work for me. Those XML attributes have no effect on the issue.